# MYSQL Count with INNER JOIN not working

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

1) outreach

```
id  profile_id  url
-------------------------
1    2        www.test.com
2    3        www.google.com 
3    4        www.example.com
4    2        www.test2.com
5    2        www.test3.com
6    2        www.test4.com
```

2). outreach_links

```
id  outreach_id  start_date             created_at        cost    status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1           2016-12-01 00:00:00  2016-12-07 00:00:00  100.00  Approved
2    1           2016-12-02 00:00:00  2016-12-09 00:00:00  120.00  Approved
3    1           NUll                 2016-12-28 00:00:00  20.00   Pending
4    1           2016-12-05 00:00:00  2016-12-10 00:00:00  35.00   Approved
5    1           2016-12-07 00:00:00  2016-12-13 00:00:00  10.00   Approved
6    2           2016-12-10 00:00:00  2016-12-15 00:00:00  10.00   Pending
7    2           2016-12-13 00:00:00  2016-12-18 00:00:00  10.00   Approved
8    2           2016-12-01 00:00:00  2016-12-28 00:00:00  10.00   Pending
9    2           2016-12-04 00:00:00  2016-12-21 00:00:00  10.00   Approved
10   2           2016-12-09 00:00:00  2016-12-22 00:00:00  15.00   Pending
```

I am trying to do a count by Month/Year and I thought its working but I think its not working because of "profile_id" issue here is my query:

```
select monthname(date) as Month,  year(date) as Year,  month(date) as Mn, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(year(date),"-",month(date),"-","01")) as tt,
(select count(*) from outreach_links where year(outreach_links.created_at) = year and month(outreach_links.created_at) = month and status = "Pending" and created_at>="2016-12-01 00:00:00" and created_at<="2016-12-31 00:00:00") as pp,
(select count(*) from outreach_links where year(outreach_links.start_date) = year and month(outreach_links.start_date) = month and status = "Approved" and start_date>="2016-12-01 00:00:00" and start_date<="2016-12-31 00:00:00") as aa,
(select sum(cost) from outreach_links where year(outreach_links.start_date) = year and month(outreach_links.start_date) = month and status = "Approved" and start_date>="2016-12-01 00:00:00" and start_date<="2016-12-31 00:00:00") as cc
from
(select year(outreach_links.created_at) as year, month(outreach_links.created_at) as month, outreach_links.created_at as date 
from outreach_links 
inner join outreach on outreach.id = outreach_links.outreach_id
where outreach_links.created_at>="2016-12-01 00:00:00" and outreach_links.created_at<="2016-12-31 00:00:00" and outreach.profile_id=2
union
select year(outreach_links.start_date) as year, month(outreach_links.start_date) as month, outreach_links.start_date as date
from outreach_links 
inner join outreach on outreach.id = outreach_id
where start_date>="2016-12-01 00:00:00" and start_date<="2016-12-31 00:00:00" and outreach.profile_id=2 ) t1
group by year, month
order by date
```

So I am doing a date range from "2016-12-01 00:00:00" to "2016-12-31 00:00:00" these could be any date range inputed by the user , and try to do a count based on outreach.profile_id = 2 , my output is wrong its counting everything for all profile_ids, I am not sure why

***Note: this is just a sample of the tables , there might be more records and the user inputed Date range from to could be different , I want to group them by Month / Year***

here is my output: ( its counting ALL records)

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#394 ▼
    +"Month": "December"
    +"Year": "2016"
    +"Mn": "12"
    +"tt": "1480568400.000000"
    +"pp": "4"
    +"aa": "6"
    +"cc": "285.00"
  }
]
```

Which is wrong it should count only for profile_id=2 , ***here is the DESIRED output I want:***

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#394 ▼
    +"Month": "December"
    +"Year": "2016"
    +"Mn": "12"
    +"tt": "1480568400.000000"
    +"pp": "1"
    +"aa": "4"
    +"cc": "265.00"
  }
]
```

As you can see the 3 counts are wrong they suppose to be: 
    "pp": "1"
    "aa": "4"
    "cc": "265.00"

here is what I am looking for:

```
1). **"pp" is Total Pending** Count when status="Pending" based on created_at
2). **"aa" is Total Approved** Count when status="Approved" based on start_date 
3). **"cc" is Total Cost** Sum of All cost when Status="Approved" and based on start_date
4). Group by Month & Year of the user imputed Date Range
```

here is a  SQLFIDDLE >> [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87dfa8/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1f7053/2)

can you please help me fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe in plain words what it is you want to count, aggregate, etc.? Hard to understand just looking at the query.

Comment: 3 things to count for : 1. Total approved for if it's between start_date 2. Total pending based on created_date range 3. Total cost based only when status approved and on start date between inputed range and all these needs to be only for inputed profile_id , note the date range could change by the given user

Comment: I want to group them all by Month and Year , same as the outputted array. is it clearer now?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I will do a SQL Fiddle to make it clearer it should be simple

Comment: I created one >>  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1f7053/2  does that make it easier??

Comment: Wouldn't the totals be 0, 4, and 265??

Comment: no , pp = 1 because we have 1 pending  at created_at = 2016-12-28 00:00:00

Comment: basically a profile has many outreachs and outreach has many outreach_links, that's kinds is the logic here

Comment: But there is no corresponding row in outreach !!?! outreach.profile id = 2 (1, 2 , 'www.test.com') only where outreach.id = 1 (before the edit, anyway)

Comment: The relationship between outreach & outreach tables is 'id' and 'outreach_id', but I want to get all based on the profile_id which is at 'outreach' table. you see my point?

Comment: So for profile_id = 2 , I need to look for outreach_ids [1,4,5,6] in outreach_links table only and do my counting , you get my point?

Comment: I updated the link to add more data >> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87dfa8/1 but the result is the same nothing changed

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this:

```
 SELECT MONTHNAME(d.date)  AS Month
      , YEAR(d.date)       AS Year
      , MONTH(d.date)      AS Mn
      , SUM(IF(l.status = 'Pending'  AND l.created_at >= d.date AND l.created_at < d.date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH ,1     ,0)) AS pp
      , SUM(IF(l.status = 'Approved' AND l.start_date >= d.date AND l.start_date < d.date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH ,1     ,0)) AS aa
      , SUM(IF(l.status = 'Approved' AND l.start_date >= d.date AND l.start_date < d.date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH ,l.cost,0)) AS cc
   FROM ( SELECT '2016-12-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AS date ) d
   JOIN outreach o
     ON o.profile_id = 2
   LEFT
   JOIN outreach_links l
     ON l.outreach_id = o.id
    AND (  (     l.start_date >= d.date + INTERVAL 0 MONTH
             AND l.start_date <  d.date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
           )
        OR (     l.created_at >= d.date + INTERVAL 0 MONTH
             AND l.created_at <  d.date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
           )
        )
  GROUP BY d.date
```

---

**EDIT**

To specify the end date of the range along with the start date, the inline view `d` can return two date values. And the outer query can reference the second date value, in this example `d.end_date`, as well as the start of the range `d.date`.

```
 SELECT MONTHNAME(d.date)  AS Month
      , YEAR(d.date)       AS Year
      , MONTH(d.date)      AS Mn
      , SUM(IF(l.status = 'Pending'  AND l.created_at >= d.date AND l.created_at < d.end_date,1     ,0)) AS pp
      , SUM(IF(l.status = 'Approved' AND l.start_date >= d.date AND l.start_date < d.end_date,1     ,0)) AS aa
      , SUM(IF(l.status = 'Approved' AND l.start_date >= d.date AND l.start_date < d.end_date,l.cost,0)) AS cc
   FROM ( SELECT '2016-12-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AS date
               , '2016-12-16' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH AS end_date
         ) d
   JOIN outreach o
     ON o.profile_id = 2
   LEFT
   JOIN outreach_links l
     ON l.outreach_id = o.id
    AND (  (     l.start_date >= d.date
             AND l.start_date <  d.end_date
           )
        OR (     l.created_at >= d.date
             AND l.created_at <  d.end_date
           )
        )
  GROUP BY d.date, d.end_date
```

Comment: What does interval do ?

Comment: i need to keep both dates inputed bc these could change and not nessary a month i could enter 2016-12-01 to 2016-12-15 or any other date and it will count

Comment: I included a second version, which allows the end date to be provided. The outer query references the values returned by the inline view `d`, so the two date values are provided only one time in the query, not multiple times.    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1f7053/11